# When in the history and literature is for the first time spoken about a more empathetically moral?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, theology, christianity

Some people say that the moral based from the point of view of another person started with Christianity.

The Anglo in the past history would say that it is not good to rob a bag of an old lady because if you pich from the weak you will despite yourself. But after and due to Christianity the emphasize was more on the fact that the robbery would cause harm and turmoil to the lady.

So there was a change from the perspective of what moral is. But when in history and literature is for the first time spoken about a more empathetically moral. Is that really after Jesus had spoken or also before Jesus?

See min 3:44

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgESPmh-TxY

Comment: Isn't this more of a question for History SE or Christianity SE?

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading carefully enough but what is the question about philosophy here?

Answer (score 3):

A more common (but still debatable claim) is that with Christianity, religion and philosophy fused in a way that had not before in the west (that is, Greek and Roman pagan theology did not dialog with philosophy in the way that, eg Augustine or Aquinas seemed to work in the overlap between the two).

To answer your question, consider these three examples:

- [Aquinas's work in general was greatly influenced by Aristotle](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aquinas/#ThoAri), as well as his [moral philosophy](http://www.iep.utm.edu/aq-moral/). Obviously, being Christian, he would say something like Aristotle lacked the full knowledge of morality, but his work certainly indicates Aquinas's approval of large parts of Aristotle's morality and ethics.
- Augustine discusses the influence of Pagan philosophy on his [conversion to Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confessions_(Augustine)), but in particular looked to Cicero as a hero, frequently citing [Hortensius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortensius_(Cicero)) (a work that is unfortunately lost).
- It was a particularly thorny problem in Medieval theology and philosophy what to do about Socrates - he was a pagan, but he was also acknowledged as one of the wisest, and therefore one of the most moral, people in history. [Aquinas and his teacher, Albert, grappled with this issue.](http://historyofphilosophy.net/albert-aquinas-ethics)

So, just based on these three data points, it's safe to say that morality is *not* a Christian invention, given that three prominent Christian philosophers (Augustine, Albert and Aquinas) think otherwise.